# youtube-dl preserve slashes in video title

Tags: youtube-dl, filename

If a video is titled "5/12", then using `%(title)s` produces "5_12". Is there any way to preserve special characters in the filename? I would be okay with something like "5%2F12".

Alternatively if there's a fast way to download *only video names* from a playlist (`-e` or `-j` seems do to one video at a time) I will accept that as well.

`--get-title` does one video at a time for playlists. In fact when using `--download-archive` the names are all printed, albeit with extra text.

Comment: Having a "/" in a file name would be a problem. It would be interpreted as a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`youtube-dl -J --flat-playlist` produces a JSON dump for the whole playlist, including the original titles (with escaped double quotes). `-j` for a JSON dump of each video.